# Loop through JSON Array Items with Angular ngFor one at a time

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, ngfor

I am using `ngFor` to loop through the JSON array and show values of a Dictionary property with another `ngFor`

The current implementation is like below

```
    <div *ngFor='let item of jsonItems' class="row">
      <div class="col-3">
        ConfidenceLevel: {{item.ConfidenceLevel}}
        <p>
          <button click="markAsSelected()">Select </button>
          <button click="showNextItem()">Show Next</button>
        </p>
       
      </div>
      <div class="col-9 table-responsive">
        <table class="table  table-bordered">
          <tr *ngFor="let obj of item.DictionaryMaster| keyvalue; let i=index" >
            <ng-container *ngIf="i<2"> //limit to show only 2 items from the list 
              <td *ngFor='let obj1 of obj.value | keyvalue'>
                {{ obj1.value }}
              </td>
            </ng-container>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
      </div>
```

Typescript code is like below

```
  jsonItems = [{   
  "ConfidenceLevel": 98.6,
  "Page": 1,
  "DictionaryMaster": {
    "0": {
      "0": "No",
      "1": "94041"
    },
    "1": {
      "0": "Date",
      "1": "08 / 06 / 2020"
    },
    "2": {
      "0": "Due",
      "1": "15 / 06 / 2020"
    },
    "3": {
      "0": " No",
      "1": "113003"
    }
  }
}, { 
  "ConfidenceLevel": 98.56,
  "Page": 1,
  "DictionaryMaster": {
    "0": {
      "0": "Net",
      "1": "\u00a3 212.40"
    },
    "1": {
      "0": "Carriage",
      "1": "\u00a3 0.00"
    },
    "2": {
      "0": "Total  Amount",
      "1": "\u00a3 42.48"
    },
    "3": {
      "0": "Order ",
      "1": "\u00a3 254.88"
    }
  }
}, {
  "CharacterConfidence": 99.72,
  "ConfidenceLevel": 90.26,
  "Page": 1,
  "DictionaryMaster": {
    "0": {
      "0": "Qty  ",
      "1": "  Code",
      "2": "  Description",
      "3": "  Price",
      "4": "  Amount"
    },
    "1": {
      "0": "24",
      "1": "42097805",
      "2": "  Ball  - Red",
      "3": "8.85",
      "4": "212.40"
    },
    "2": {
      "0": "24",
      "1": "42097805",
      "2": "Ball  Red",
      "3": "8.85",
      "4": "212.40"
    },
    "3": {
      "0": "24",
      "1": "42097805",
      "2": " Red",
      "3": "8.85",
      "4": "212.40"
    },
    "4": {
      "0": "24",
      "1": "42097805",
        "2": " - Red",
      "3": "8.85",
      "4": "212.40"
    }
  }
}];

  markAsSelected = function () {
      //not sure how to fetch the selected item with index / 
       some other means }

  showNextItem = function () {

  }
```

This will render all the items of my Json array as a table at present . Ideally i would like to render one table at a time.

Can we limit the ngFor to display one set of items at a time from  this list and on click event of button show next item

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use `slice` for your object `jsonItems`:

```
 <div *ngFor="let item of jsonItems.slice(StartIndex, StartIndex + 1)" class="row">
   ...
</div>
```

And then in your code:

```
StartIndex = 0;
  showNextItem() {
    if (this.StartIndex + 1 < this.jsonItems.length) this.StartIndex++;
  }
  showPreviousItem() {
    if (this.StartIndex > 0) this.StartIndex--;
  }
```

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-template-xx2sjq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) is working sample.

But you know if you want to show one item at a time you don't need `ngFor`. You just need to use current index of your object. But I give a solution with `ngFor` for extensibility purposes such as show two or three items at a time or something like that.

Comment: I am trying to show one item at a time.( Not dictionary ) In the example json 3 objects are there. So show item(0) as default. On click of button show items(1) and then items(2).; The contents inside main ngFor remains the same

Comment: @sebastian Ok I got it. I updated my answer and code. Please check that.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to view one at a time, then you do not need `*ngFor`. Let a variable initialize at 0 in the typescript module for the typescript code. Define a method to increment the `currentIndex`. Very simplified code just to show the approach.

```js
currentIndex = 0;
currentItem = jsonItems[this.currentIndex];
nextItem () {
  this.currentIndex++;
  this.currentItem = this.jsonItems[this.currentIndex];
}
```

```html
<div (click)="nextItem()">{{ currentItem.ConfidenceLevel }}</div>
```

Or...

```html
<div>
  <p>{{ currentItem.ConfidenceLevel }}</p>
  <button (click)="nextItem()">Next</button>
</div>
```

This will improve the rendering speed of your view, since you are not rendering the entire array using `*ngFor`. Otherwise, you must render the whole array in `divs`, and then use typescript to control CSS to determine which of the already-rendered-but-hidden `divs` are displayed.